# Определить, содержит ли строка число в данной системе счисления

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Можно ли регуляркой найти в строке все числа разных (2, 8, 10, 16) систем счисления? Или же может быть есть подходящая команда на PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для 16-ричной системы числа будут состоять из цифр диапазона `[0-9A-F]`. Для 15 - `[0-9A-E]`, для 14 - `[0-9A-D]`, для 10 - `[0-9]` (`\d`), для 8 - `[0-7]`, и т.д. Если же вам при этом нужно понимать, в какой именно системе выцеплено число, то давайте более чёткие критерии. Например, 16-ричным будет считаться число вида `0xAF` или `0AFh`, и так - по **каждой** системе. Потому что иначе мы не сможем понять, к какой системе, например, принадлежит `10`? `123`? Или `dead beef` - это два числа или два слова?

---

По результатам. Задача не такая уж и простая. Например, если мы ограничиваемся только десятичными числами в трёх форматах (целое, с плавающей точкой, экспоненциальная форма), то шаблон может быть такой:

```
/([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}\\.{0,1}[0-9]{0,})(E-{0,1}[0-9]{1,}){0,1}/i
```

(чуть поправленная версия из [этой статьи](https://snx.su/post/parse-number-of-exponential-form))

Comment: Всё проще, только найти.
Спасибо, это помогло. 
Скажите, можно регуляркой выявить одним числом 0.31e ?

Comment: Ищите :) Для этого вам должно хватить информации. Или что-то конкретное не получается?

Comment: Конкретно..
http://dok2d.ru/cr/1.php - Вот работа, которую я делаю. 
Там может оказаться любое число, с точкой или запятой, с буквой, например.
Обрабатывать их не надо, просто выявить.

Comment: "Там" это где, в этом исходнике? Тогда я вообще не понимаю проблемы. Ещё раз: сформулируйте критерии, по которым будете выделять числа (например, `несколько десятичных цифр подряд` или `символы из всего диапазона и хотя бы одна десятичная цифра` и т.д. ) По этим критериям и выцепляйте, используя диапазоны, которые я привёл.

Comment: Да, даётся произвольный код, тот что там - это пример.
Скрипты анализируют и выводят операторы, слова и цифры.
А цифры там могут быть в двоичной, восьмеричной, десятеричной и шестнадцатеричной СС, могут быть с точкой, с запятой, а также с умножением на число Эйлера [e].
Там, как пример, уже есть такое 0.31e, но оно выявляется как 0 и 31e.

Comment: И в третий раз: либо вы формулируете чёткие критерии, по которым выделяете числа, либо вопрос не имеет смысла. Без понимания что именно нужно сделать никакой регексп не написать.

Comment: Например: https://snx.su/post/parse-number-of-exponential-form

Comment: Вот, почти то что нужно. Спасибо, и извините, что невнятно развёртывал вопрос. Времени мало.. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, там шаблон слегка неточный :) Если нужно не просто находить тсаик числа, а получать , то его надо чуть поправить: `/[+-]{0,1}([0-9]{1,}\\.{0,1}[0-9]{0,})(E-{0,1}([0-9]{1,})){0,1}/` Сейчас в ответ внесу.